# How to get the second data in the linked list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

I have tried to read from a text file two values: `130,220` (delimited by comma). However, I have created a linked list of nodes that have `dato1` and `dato2` attributes where I want to save these values.

When I print the `obtenerNodos` method from my reader class, print only the first value (130) duplicated.

```
[130, 130]
```

How can I edit `obtenerNodos` method for `dato1` and `dato2`?

I expect: `[130,220]` stored correctly in linked list.

Below is the code for the nodes and linked list.

**Node class**

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, dato1 = None, dato2 = None, siguienteNodo = None):
    self.dato1 = dato1
    self.dato2 = dato2
    self.siguienteNodo = siguienteNodo
```

**Linked List class**

```
class ListaEnlazada:

    def __init__(self):
       self.nodoInicio = Nodo()
       self.nodoUltimo = Nodo()

    def tamano(self):
       actual = self.nodoInicio
       total = 0
       while actual.siguienteNodo != None:
           total += 1
           actual = actual.siguienteNodo
       return total


    def agregarNodoFinal(self, dato1, dato2):
       nodoNuevo = Nodo(dato1, dato2)
       actual = self.nodoInicio
       while actual.siguienteNodo is not None:
           actual = actual.siguienteNodo
       actual.siguienteNodo = nodoNuevo 


    def obtenerNodos(self):
       datos = []
       nodo = self.nodoInicio
       while nodo.siguienteNodo is not None:
          nodo = nodo.siguienteNodo
          datos.append(nodo.dato1)
       return datos   


    def vacia(self):
       if self.nodoInicio == None:
          return True
       else:
          return False
```

**Reader class** ( I'm not sure if my reader is working correctly)

```
class LecturaArchivo:
     listaEnlazada = ListaEnlazada()

     nombreArchivo = input('Nombre del archivo: ')
     archivo = open(nombreArchivo, "r")
     lineas = archivo.read()
     datos = lineas.split(',')

     for dato in datos:
        xTemporal = float(datos[0])
        yTemporal = float(datos[1])

        listaEnlazada.agregarNodoFinal((xTemporal), (yTemporal))

     print(listaEnlazada.obtenerNodos())
```

Comment: Your problem is with this code: `datos.append(nodo.dato1)`
You are appending `nodo.dato1` every time inside the `while` loop in method `obtenerNodos()`.  You are never appending the second (or any other subsequent) value in your list.

Comment: What I have to do is append: `datos.append(nodo.dato1)` and `datos.append(nodo.dato2)` outside the `while` loop, is that correct?

Comment: That will work if your list only ever has 2 nodes in it.  In general, a *linked* list has every node holding a reference to the next node, and you would iterate through the list using these references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: It works!!!!!!!